# DbContext doesn't instantiate navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I created two entities with a simple 1 to many relationship.

```
public class TestEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RelatedTest> RelatedTests { get; set; }
}

public class RelatedTest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Something { get; set; }

    public virtual TestEntity TestEntity { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to test this the `ICollection` navigation property isn't instantiated. I can't add a related entity.

```
var dataContext = new DataContext();
var testEntity = new TestEntity { Message = "Test message" };
var related = new RelatedTest { Something = true };
testEntity.RelatedTests.Add(related); //fails on this line because RelatedTests is null.
dataContext.TestEntities.Add(testEntity);
dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Is that the expected functionality? Do I have to instantiate the navigation property? I expected Entity Framework to instantiate the collection for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your above example you probably want something more like

```
var dataContext = new DataContext();
var testEntity = new TestEntity { Message = "Test message" };
var related = new RelatedTest { Something = true };
testEntity.RelatedTests = new List<RelatedTest>{related};
dataContext.TestEntities.Add(testEntity);
dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

as you are creating the base entity so EF hasnt yet gotten its hands on the entity to do any fixups.

When you reload this entity from the database the collection shouldn't be null in your above example as you appear to be using lazy loading.

Comment: Why not just override the setter of the entity and init it there, saves having to write the initialisation more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Well, entity framework does not 'initialize' any of your objects (except with data ALREADY IN THE DATABASE). You have to do it yourself. EF only 'maps it to the database'.

Comment: So it will only instantiate the navigation property collection if it is retrieved from DbContext and has related entities already?

Comment: I feel you need a constructor for the class that 'initializes' your object.

Comment: Not quite right Alex, it shouldn't need related entities already - should be initialised to an empty collection if it's loaded from the database and there aren't any related entities.